# Powershell command did not include error in output file

Tags: powershell, ip, host, server-name

I have the code below, to be used in Powershell; it performed well, except that I need the output file to also include the error messages whenever the IPs did not resolve to names.

```
Get-Content inputfile.txt | 
    foreach-object { [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_)  } | 
    out-file -filepath outputfile.txt
```

At the moment, I'm able to see the red error messages displayed on Powershell window. But I want these to appear in the output file along with the results  for each item listed in the input file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exceptions produced by `GetHostEntry` don't give you a hint as to which IP failed to be resolved

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Is there a way around this? :(

Comment: If a command produces errors and you want them as part of stdout, you can join errors with stdout by use `2>&1` for example `get-process 2>&1` this simply puts stderr (2) into the stdout (1) stream. This is remnant of command line. The more PowerShell way would involve using the $error variable to spit out the last error as you wish. $error has many properties that you can break apart as you want. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-error?view=powershell-7.2 ... You probably need a try catch block to ensure errors only go out when they happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`.GetHostEntry(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=net-6.0) doesn't give you a clear hint as to which IP failed to be resolved it's better if you create an object that associates the IP Address you're trying to resolve with the *method call*. This also allows you to have a better export type, instead of plain `.txt` file, you can export your objects as `.csv` with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2).

Below example uses [`.GetHostEntryAsync(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentryasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-dns-gethostentryasync(system-net-ipaddress)) which allow us to query multiple hosts in parallel!

```sh
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Collections.Specialized

(Get-Content inputfile.txt).ForEach{
    begin { $tasks = [List[OrderedDictionary]]::new() }
    process {
        $tasks.Add([ordered]@{
            Input    = $_
            Hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntryAsync($_)
        })
    }
    end {
        do {
            $id = [System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::WaitAny($tasks.Hostname, 200)
            if($id -eq -1) { continue }
            $thisTask = $tasks[$id]
            $thisTask['Hostname'] = try {
                $thisTask.Hostname.GetAwaiter().GetResult().HostName
            }
            catch { $_.Exception.Message }
            $tasks.RemoveAt($id)
            [pscustomobject] $thisTask
        } while($tasks)
    }
} | Export-Csv outputfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is a really nice combination of PowerShell, .NET, and Async/Task +1

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I have a similar function in [this repo](https://github.com/santysq/PowerShell-Network-Scanners) you might find them useful :)

Comment: @Santiago I have marked the answer as the solution. Thanks again. I might ask at least one  more networking-related question using PowerShell in a few hours, I hope you participate again :)